# Lorawan packets datasets

Tags: lorawan

I'm studying Lorawan protocol. I would like to know if
some datasets exist to study LoRaWAN packets, parameters and some features.

Comment: have you done any research on the web?

Comment: yes but I did not find anything

Comment: I haven't looked into lowran, but have worked with the [OSI 7 layer model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) all my life. Obviously, there will be layer 1 changes, possibly layer 2, and probably not layer 3, certainly not in layers 4 to 7, when compared to other protocols. Can you tell us what part of the protocol stack interests you? Presumably just message transmission, without understanding the content of most of what is being transmitted. There will be a message header + a payload & it seems that the payload doesn't interest you? Consider HTTP - are you interested in TCP, IP, other?

Comment: I need to find the metadata within Lorawan packets. For instance, you could see this link: https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder/blob/master/PROTOCOL.TXT (from line 128) to understand what I meant. I need several outcomes of those metadata.

Comment: Legitimate question. There is a severe lack of test cases and sample frames with detailed explanations. Have you tried contacting Semtech and the LoRa Alliance ? They should do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the LoRaWAN specification that explains every single bit of a LoRaWAN frame. [LoRaWAN® Specification v1.0.3](https://lora-alliance.org/resource_hub/lorawan-specification-v1-0-3/)